# Why doesn't sed 's/a*//' regex match all a's?

Tags: regex, sed

What is the reason that this sed replacement

```
echo "xaaa" | sed  's/a*//'
```

yields `xaaa`. Isn't it trying to replace any consecutive a's by nothing?

Comment: See: [The Stack Overflow Regular Expressions FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/3776858)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you add `g` (for Global) after the last `/`, `sed` will only replace the first match.

Your `a*` regex matches an empty string (`*` means zero or more), so it replaces the empty string before `x` with another empty string an then stops.

Answer (score 3):

It is because `*` means `0` or more matches so it matches an empty string and replaces with nothing.

However if you add `g` (global) flag then it replaces all `a`s:

```
echo "xaaa" | sed 's/a*//g'
x
```

Comment: It reduces the number of replacement in the string `xaaa` by one, but it *increases* the number of replacements in `Some line with the string xaaa` by ~25

Answer (score 0):

No need to use the `*` operator if you are using global substitution:

```
echo "xaaa" | sed 's/a//g'
x
```

The `g` flag ensures that all occurrences of the pattern are replaced.